# JSON to Java Object without creating class (PHP way)

Tags: java, php, json, object

I am dealing with json data fetched from twitter API

on PHP I normally do something like:

`$data = json_decode($response);`
and the `$data` would be STD class object

I want to do the same thing in Java.

I took a look at Gson, but I need a second argument which seems like I need to create a specific class for the fetched data.

The basic question is how can I convert JSON to Standard Java Object like in PHP (STD Class Object)

Thank You

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read it into a map using Jackson then you can access whatever data you want.  For instance, if your json looks like this

```
{ "name":"blah",
  "address": {
    "line1": "1234 my street",
    "city": "my city",
    "state": "my state"
  }
}
```

Then you could:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> mystuff = mapper.readValue( jsonString, Map.class );
String name = (String)mystuff.get("name");
String city = ((Map<String, Object>)mystuff.get( "address" )).get( "city" );
```

Comment: this seems simple. I will try this

Comment: I'm using this in a couple of unit tests where I'm testing code that produces JSON and it works well. It is pretty simple and Jackson is fast.

Comment: String city = ((Map<String, Object>)mystuff.get( "address" )).get( "city" ); gave me an issue that it was an object, not a string. 

added .toString() to fix it

Answer (score 3):

If your JSON data does not follow a specific structure, don't use GSON, but a regular JSON library (like the one from [json.org](http://json.org/)) that will give you an instance of a class like `JSONObject`, from which you can access data like `jsonObject.getString("key")`.

Comment: +1 json.org - simple and sufficient in most cases (added the link to json.org on your answer - hope you dont mind)

Comment: this can solve the problem, but how can I access a nested object inside the object?

Comment: @bn - by calling `jsonObject.getObject("key")`.  Read the javadocs.

Comment: How do you want to get an object if you don't want to have a class? Maybe I didn't understand your initial question

Comment: for example i want to access nested object like this in PHP
$data->resultset->result->username.
How can I do this in Java?

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard class object in Java and thus you need a class. You could dynamically create and compile the class at runtime but I doubt that's worth the trouble.

Answer (score -1):

When json_encode doesn't exist on a PHP server, I use this:

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('json_encode'))
{
  function json_encode($a=false)
  {
    if (is_null($a)) return 'null';
    if ($a === false) return 'false';
    if ($a === true) return 'true';
    if (is_scalar($a))
    {
      if (is_float($a))
      {
        // Always use "." for floats.
        return floatval(str_replace(",", ".", strval($a)));
      }

      if (is_string($a))
      {
        static $jsonReplaces = array(array("\\", "/", "\n", "\t", "\r", "\b", "\f", '"'), array('\\\\', '\\/', '\\n', '\\t', '\\r', '\\b', '\\f', '\"'));
        return '"' . str_replace($jsonReplaces[0], $jsonReplaces[1], $a) . '"';
      }
      else
        return $a;
    }
    $isList = true;
    for ($i = 0, reset($a); $i < count($a); $i++, next($a))
    {
      if (key($a) !== $i)
      {
        $isList = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    $result = array();
    if ($isList)
    {
      foreach ($a as $v) $result[] = json_encode($v);
      return '[' . join(',', $result) . ']';
    }
    else
    {
      foreach ($a as $k => $v) $result[] = json_encode($k).':'.json_encode($v);
      return '{' . join(',', $result) . '}';
    }
  }
}
?>
```

If you could rewrite this in Java then it should to the trick for you.

Ref:(Dead link)http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/7487